# New Doom Emacs user - trying to set global-set-key

Tags: emacs

I've installed neotree in Doom Emacs.  I would like to bind function key 8 ([f8]) using global-set-key.    i've put

```
(global-set-key [f8] 'neotree-toggle)
```

in init.el, config.el, and custome.el.  When I press f8, emacs says " is undefined".

if i type in ":neotree-toggle", it works.

Can you help?

Comment: I'd start with trying "<f8>" rather than [f8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In emacs-lisp (elisp), keys can be represented in different ways, vector or string. The usual way to represent them is to use the macro kbd (for keybinding of course) that transforms a simple string like "C-h f" to the key representing CTRL+h f.

If you want to learn more about that you can read the emacs manual about keys [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html), or this blog post that is pretty good [here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs).

Finally, if you look at the description of the function global-set-key with `C-h f RET global-set-key` :

```
global-set-key is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘subr.el’.

(global-set-key KEY COMMAND)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 1.4.

Give KEY a global binding as COMMAND.
COMMAND is the command definition to use; usually it is
a symbol naming an interactively-callable function.
KEY is a key sequence; noninteractively, it is a string or vector
of characters or event types, and non-ASCII characters with codes
above 127 (such as ISO Latin-1) can be included if you use a vector.

Note that if KEY has a local binding in the current buffer,
that local binding will continue to shadow any global binding
that you make with this function.
```

You have to give it a key than a command, so in your case, it'll be something like :

`(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") 'neotree-toggle)`

See how special keys are dealt with with kbd [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a few minutes, and since I'm already using doom I did a little experimentation. This should work for you:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") #'neotree)
```